# How can I find the maximum value within a string? excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have a few cells that are formatted as text, that need to be analyzed individually. Each cell contains 14 digits (i.e. 14684968487347) and I need to determine the highest individual digit per cell. I figured I could just adjust a left/right formula to break it out but I figured I would try to find a way to cut down the file size.

Comment: What do you mean by "individual number"? You mean simply the highest of whichever of the digits from 0-9 is present in the string?

Comment: Correct, if the cell containted 1234, then 4 would be the result.

Comment: He said "highest individual digit per cell". It seems like he wants the value and not position.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way of I imagine many:

```
=MATCH(100,FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1))-1
```

Comment: The confusion may arise from the fact that this formula, when applied to the example (14684968487347), returns the number 6 instead of the number 9 – possibly as a result of truncation to scientific notation.

Comment: @Rick Hitchcock: Nothing to do with scientific notation. Just me being inept! I chose a lookup_value for MATCH which is obviously inadequate, since FIND could feasibly return a position of greater than that value if the string is greater than 10 characters in length. Have amended to a more appropriate value in the post.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. And for the vote. Both much appreciated.